# Concatenete two cells if blank cell in the next column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple spreadsheet, with 30k rows.

Under column B, I have a blank cell, this will indicate under column A the address is over two rows, I want to concatenate these 2 cells into one cell.

```
Sub Merge()

Dim LR As Integer
Dim icell As Range
Dim strMerge As String
Dim MyCell As Range

'Add new Sheet and rename it
Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets("Austin Grids")
ActiveSheet.Name = "Austin Grids1"

'Copy sheets contents from original to the new sheet
Sheets("Austin Grids").Cells.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Austin Grids1").Range("A1")

'Find last row of current sheet
LR = Worksheets("Austin Grids1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set MyCell = Sheets("Austin Grids1").Range("A:A")

'Move rows of where column is null
For Each icell In Range("B:B")
    If icell.Value = "" Then
        icell.Select
        icell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        strMerge = MyCell.Value
    End If
Next icell

End Sub
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the loop you can use for VBA.  It will start at the end, moving up row-by-row until it reaches Row 2.

```
Dim totalRows As Long, i As Long

totalRows = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

With Sheets("Austin Grids1")
For i = totalRows To 2 Step -1
    If .Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
        .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
        .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
End With
```

Comment: BruceWayne, this works nicely, is there a way to remove leading and trailing characters around the strings in column A first before joining the text? This is a learning experience for me!

Comment: @JamesNiven - Are the leading/trailing characters just spaces/whitespace? If so, you can just wrap `TRIM()` around the range, e.g. `... TRIM(.Cells(i, 1).Value) & TRIM(.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value)`

Comment: Thanks BruceWayne, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @JamesNiven - Of course!  If this answered your question, you can mark it as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post (this removes the question from the Unanswered queue).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use VBA, so if I may, I will offer a formula solution.

In `H2`, paste this formula and drag as far down as needed:

```
=IF(B1="",A1&" "&A2,"")
```

<sub>Note: You may just need `A1&A2`, I can't tell if column A actually has leading spaces in those names, or that's formatting</sub>

Then, in I2, paste this and drag right:

```
=IF($H2<>"",B2,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks BruceWayne, that does work, but then I have to replace the new value on top of the old value, this is time consuming, I was hoping a VBA solution would overwrite the old value and then I just need to delete the remaining blank rows.

Comment: @JamesNiven - So would you want to just add "Alabaster" to "Caverns Dr", then delete the "Alabaster" row (row #4)?

Comment: Yes sir that is the end goal, but like a mentioned I have two files both 30k rows each, it's really a file cleanup. Thanks

Comment: Also, the formula you suggested will be used for future projects and I do appreciate that.